# Remove Class After Passing Its ScrollTop Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I'm trying to achieve is to remove the class that I added once it passes its scrollTop position and add it back once I scroll up from below.

So I got the h1 element to show up on scroll but I want to remove it once it's out of the view port and let's say you want to go back up, you would get an animation, same as the one you would get when you initially scrolled from the top down but this time from down up.

```js
$(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wScroll > $('h1').offset().top - 300) {
      $('h1').addClass('opacity');
    } else {
      $('h1').removeClass('opacity');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
  transition: 1s all ease;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to handle the after scroll check this :

```js
$(function() {
  
$(window).scroll(function() {
var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
var hpos = $('h1').offset().top;
if (wScroll === hpos -300 ) {
  $('h1').addClass('opacity');
} else if (wScroll < hpos - 300) {
  $('h1').removeClass('opacity');
}
else if (wScroll < hpos - 300) {
  $('h1').removeClass('opacity');
}
else if (wScroll > hpos ) {
  $('h1').removeClass('opacity');
}
else {
  $('h1').addClass('opacity');
}
});
  
});
```

```css
h1 {
margin-top: 500px;
margin-bottom: 1000px;
transition: 1s all ease;
position: relative;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
}

.opacity {
opacity: 1;
color: red;
position: relative;
left: 200px;
transition: 1s all ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to solve it from short way, try this. Maybe you need to calibrate it. I don't try on fullscreen.

```
    $(function() {

      $(window).scroll(function() {
      var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

      if (wScroll > $('h1').offset().top - 300 
      && wScroll < $('h1').offset().top + 300) {
      $('h1').addClass('opacity');
      }
      else {
        $('h1').removeClass('opacity');
      }

      });

     });
```